# How to read CSV file in mysql databse using Django

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework

How to read `CSV file` in `mysql databse` using **Django**.

I want to read `csv file data using django` and `write this csv data` in **MySQL Databases**.

Comment: you cant read CSV file in MySQL database but you can read CSV file's data in python and then add it to you MySQL database for that you can use Django models but if there is not user side requirements then you can directly add that data using MySQL connector

Comment: Sir actually i am not understand that where is store CSV file in django.

Comment: Django error is CSV file not found.

Comment: first of all tell me one thing you are taking that CSV  file as a user input means every-time you have to read different CSV files or this is just one time process.could you please elaborate your question so that it will help me to work on solution code.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [django-import-export](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which covers exactly this use case.

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution whatever i understand from your question

First of all create browse button for user to take CSV file as a input and then store it temprory in apps's `static/upload` folder.Then pass the path of that file to our datastore function present in `views.py`.

forms.py

```
from django import forms

class browse(forms.Form):
    file = forms.FileField()
```

views.py

```
import csv
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
from mysql.connector import errorcode

def index(request):
    result = None
    form = None
    if request.method == 'POST':  
        form = browse(request.POST, request.FILES)  
        if form.is_valid():  
            handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file']) # store file in upload folder
            path = "static/upload/"+ str(request.FILES['file'])#path of selected file
            with open(path,'rt')as f:
                data = csv.reader(f)
                for row in data:
                    storedata(row) 
    else:
        pass

def storedata(row):
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                         database='electronics',
                                         user='root',
                                         password='root')
    mySql_insert_query = """INSERT INTO Laptop (name, fname, lname) 
                           VALUES 
                           (row[0], row[1], row[2]) """

    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(mySql_insert_query)
    connection.commit()
    print(cursor.rowcount, "Record inserted successfully into Laptop table")
    cursor.close()
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

def handle_uploaded_file(f):
    with open('static/upload/'+f.name, 'wb+') as destination:
        for chunk in f.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)
```